# How can I return view and pass in data in Laravel with Ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, view

I have an issue with my Ajax function which is supposed to call a Laravel view with `$paginatedResults` data which is returns from another function. For some reason it returns error 500. I know for a fact that $paginatedResults returns the right data as if I var_dump it's correct.

```
public function ajaxSearch(Request $request)
{
    $data = $request->input('searchVal');
    $pageNr = $request->input('pageNr');
    $dataType = $request->input('dataType');
    $paginatedResults = $this->paginateTypeResults($data, $pageNr, $filetype);

    $loadData = view('search.searchresults')->with($paginatedResults)->render();
    echo response()->json($loadData);
}
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: "message": "Illegal offset type",

Comment: It turns out that $paginatedResults is a object but I think it's supposed to be an array. But I am still unable to get it to return with my ajax function.

Comment: It returns error 500 because your server-side crashes. Anyway, which line exactly is causing the error? The render() one?

Comment: You send a rendered view (HTML) as JSON? Have you tried `return`ing instead of `echo`ing, most Laravel methods return content

Comment: Yes I have tried to return it. I can't even tell how many different things I have tried

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is json response

```
return response()->json([
   'html' => view('search.searchresults', compact('paginatedResults'))->render()
]);
```

After success

```
$.ajax({
   //
   dataType: 'json',
   success: function(response) {
      $('.//here').html(response.html)
   }
})
```